# Strict Standards error while saving register data

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am following a tutorial that creates a register and login system. I am doing everything the same, but I still get an weird Strict Standards error when I press submit on my form.

```
<?php

require 'pdoconnect.php';

$message = '';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):


// Enter the new user in the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

if( $stmt->execute() ):
    $message = 'Successfully created new user';
else:
    $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
endif;

endif;

?>
```

It says

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference on line 14 (line with password hash).

I have looked for an solution everywhere, but I am not able to find any.

Comment: You should hash the password *before* you use the hash in `bindParam()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash the password *before* you bind it:

```
// Enter the new user in the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$hashedPass = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $hashedPass );
```

You cannot pass a function to a bound parameter, you can only pass a variable.

Comment: Thanks! Passwords are now safely hashed in the database :)

Comment: well well well... look at you Mr. Fancy Pants. Now we're going to have to call you Mr. "Hot" pants Sam.

Comment: *Gitch 'yo hot pants right cheer* @JayBlanchard Huh Sam? lmho